# Close cmd window after loaded program finishes running

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I have the following code to run a bat file and open a cmd
window:

```
def issue_command(*args):
     process = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE,     stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
return process.communicate()

args = [["cmd", "/c", "start",    "c:\ABAQUS_Jobs\abaqusjob.bat", "A2", "routineUEL", "8", "1"]]

for arg in args:
    out, err = issue_command(*arg)
```

Now when the program called in the bat file ends I want the open cmd window to close. How can I do this?

EDIT:

Writing exit in the bat file didn't work. Nothing different seems to happen with exit. However I tested exit in an example hello world bat file and it did close the window. In my case the program finishes running because a message is written to the cmd window but the window does not close. I need it to close so that other python scripts can run.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `exit` command to the end of your batch file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using an `exit` command at the end of the batch file, because if you decide to run that batch file at a command prompt (e.g., to test it), it will exit from cmd.exe.

All you should need to do is remove `start` from your argument list.

Comment: I need to include start because I want to see the outputs of the program loaded in the bat file. this program writes several messages while it is executing to a cmd window.

Comment: A batch file is going to run in its own console window anyway. The cmd `start` command will spawn a second console window.

Comment: In my case it does not. I think it runs inside the python terminal or background because I can only see files being created and modified as the analysis proceeds.... that is why I included start.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python, but I would assume it lets you spawn an executable without hiding its window.